# How to serialize a final field containing a non-serializable object

Tags: java, serialization, immutability

My immutable class (all fields final) contains a reference to an object of a 3rd-party class that does not implement `Serializable`.  The usual workaround for this is (as described in the accept answer of [How to serialize a non-serializable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163872/how-to-serialize-a-non-serializable-in-java)) to use the `writeObject` and `readObject` methods to create a custom serialization format.  However, `readObject` is unable to update `final` fields because it isn't a constructor. I've seen a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26785954/441899) of using `readResolve` to work around this, but cannot see how this can work, because I don't see how to get the data necessary to initialise the final field into that method (it apparently only has access to the fields I have already initialised, and I'd really rather not create a new mutable field in the object for temporary use during deserialization when the object is supposed to be entirely immutable).  So how can I get my deserialization to work?

```
public class ThisDoesntWork implements Serializable
{
   private final transient SomeNonSerializableClass object;
   private void writeObject (ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
   {
      out.writeUTF (object.toString());
   }
   private void readObject (ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException
   {
      object = SomeNonSerializableClass.fromString(in.readUTF()); // error!
   }
}
```

Comment: You could just remove the `final` keyword. Your class is still immutable even if you remove it, because you control all access to the field. That's why you encapsulate fields. You could leave `final` as a comment, for documentation purposes, e.g. `private /*final*/ MyObject myObj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `writeReplace()` to write an object of a *different* (proxy) class, and `readResolve()` to *construct* an object of the original class from the values in the proxy. The constructor can set the final field.